# Python: Can't change variable in other file, but there is no error though

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, config, project

Found similar posts, but nothing answered my question.

I have a "configuration" file in my project folder named globalvar.py.

In it, I have the variables "latitude," "longitude," and "signalStrength."

I have another file that establishes internet connection to a cellular modem, and then writes values to these variables with:

```
globalvar.latitude = calculation
globalvar.longitude = othercalculation
globalvar.signalStrength = anothercalculation
```

When I open the globalvar.py file, I do not see the correct values written, even though I've been able to print them to console.

Similarly, I have a main Python script that is trying to send these values to Azure, and it also is unable to pick up these files.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Just to be sure I understand: you're expecting the new values to actually be *written to the file*?

Comment: Well, yes, in a sense.  So, let me explain further.  I have three scripts: globalvar, which is a place that I store variables that I want to access from multiple scripts; mainAzure which constantly sends telemetry data to IoT Hub; and connectHologram which connects my device(I'm using a raspberry pi) to the internet and then constantly loops through to get the signal strength.  I want that signal strength to be constantly updated in my main script.

Comment: Well it sounds like you want a database, perhaps a key-value store like Redis. That's the best way to persist values so they can be shared between different scripts.